# How to reserve a transaction sequence number?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, stellar-sdk

I have a multisig account and need to initiate a transaction for `set option` operation. So prepared a transaction which will be expired in 7 days and within this time all (3 out 3 signers) has to sign transaction.

How i can reserve this transaction sequence so another transaction can't use this sequence ? can't use Bump Sequence as document says. also try to use future sequence number which also don't work.

[This operation invalidates any transactions with a smaller sequence number, and is often utilized in complex contracting scenarios.](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/start/list-of-operations/#bump-sequence)

how can i do this ?

> Example:

```
Master account signing weight : 0
low Threshold : 1
Medium Threshold : 2
High Threshold : 3

Signer 1 weight: 1
Signer 2 weight: 1
Signer 3 weight: 1
```

Initiated a `set options` transaction with master account public key with expiration of 7 days, let's suppose current sequence is `56545222`. Here i have build the transaction envelope with sequence `56545222` but this need to sign by all `3 signers` within 7 days to submit this to network.

meanwhile within this time duration master account may require to submit some other transactions like any `low threshold` transaction, so the aim to reserve `56545222` sequence number and the new `low threshold` transaction may use sequence `56545223`. and this should not invalidate transaction with sequence `56545222`.

or is there any other way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Sequence number management is "low" threshold, so if you want to ensure that this specific pre-signed transaction cannot be invalidated by a subset of signers, you will have to set thresholds to 0:3:3:3. That said, it sounds like you want to allow this account to do some other thing in the interim.

An alternative is to use a different account "B" with the same signers, and threshold 0:3:3:3 that will be used exclusively by those pre-signed transactions.

Account B @ seqNum 1234

```
tx: {
   sourceAcccount: B,
   seq: 1234,
   timebound: ct > some_date,
   ops: [
    {
       sourceAccount: A,  ### this operation will target account A
       setOptions ... 
    }
   ]
}
```

Here `tx` does what you wanted to do: it changes signers from account A but consumes a sequence number from account B so there is no chance of conflict between use cases.

This account B can actually have many more presigned transactions after that, that could even be shared ahead of time.